# How to remove this object?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I'm trying to remove the red part of the tooth image. How do I remove vertices and faces?

[red object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4uxg.png)

I am using the tooth image provided at ([tooth image data](https://github.com/limhoyeon/ToothGroupNetwork))

I need your help. Thank you.

The image was cropped by specifying the range of the x, y, and z axes. However, I am not sure if this method will apply well to other data. And I want to get rid of it cleanly. I am working with Python or Matlab.

[How I Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHqNU.png)